# How to use nhibernate ToFuture query with nhibernte linq

Tags: linq-to-nhibernate, nhibernate-3

Does ToFuture works with nhibernate linq? If so, how do you use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does.  Here's a simple example:

```cs
var blogs = _session.Query<Blog>()
    .Take(30)
    .ToFuture();
var blogCount= _session.Query<Blog>()
    .ToFutureValue(x => x.Count());

Console.WriteLine(blogCount.Value); // DB is queried here.
```

Here's an example of where I've used it for a customer search form that displayed paged search results and and a total count of search results.  Notice you can reuse an IQueryable to create two futures.  The Filter methods built an IQueryable based on what fields the user searched by.

```cs
int resultsPerPage = 50;
var query = _session.Query<CustomerSearch>()
    .FilterById(model)
    .FilterByFirstName(model)
    .FilterByLastName(model)
    .FilterBySocialSecurityNumber(model)    
    .FilterByPrimaryPhoneNumber(model);
var futureResults = query
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .Skip(model.Page * resultsPerPage)
    .Take(resultsPerPage)
    .ToFuture();
var futureCount = query.ToFutureValue(x => x.Count());
```

Answer (score 5):

Be carefull ToFuture only works if the database driver supports MulitpleQueries. This is only the case in some drivers (eg. MySql, SqlServer) but not in all (eg. Oracle)